# Draw a transparent box (over a grid)

Tags: metapost, transparency

How can I draw a transparent box in Metafont? I would like to have something like the legend in this graph: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Articlecount_topten_wikipedia.svg. You could say I want to "override" the background (in the example above the grid) of the box with transparency.

Comment: The legend in your link is not transparent, it just uses a white background.  Normally this is done with colorbox, although you can achieve the same effect with \rlap \color and \rule.

Answer (score 2):

[I'm assuming we are talking MetaPost rather than MetaFont].

You can do transparency in MetaPost by iterating over all the components of a picture and re-colouring them appropriately.  Here's an example of a grid and simple transparent rectangle.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
% parameters
u = 1cm;
ymax = xmax = 2.75;
xmin = ymin = -2.75;

% make a plain grid
path xx, yy;
xx = ((xmin,0) -- (xmax,0)) scaled u;
yy = ((0,ymin) -- (0,ymax)) scaled u;

drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled .5 withcolor .7 white);
for i = ceiling ymin upto floor ymax: draw xx shifted (0,i*u); endfor
for i = ceiling xmin upto floor xmax: draw yy shifted (i*u,0); endfor

drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled .7);
xx := xx scaled 1.05;
yy := yy scaled 1.05;
drawarrow xx;
drawarrow yy;
drawoptions();

label.rt (btex $x$ etex, point infinity of xx);
label.top(btex $y$ etex, point infinity of yy);

% draw the "transparent" box
path box; box = unitsquare shifted 1/2 down shifted 1/4 left scaled 3cm;

alpha = 5/8;  % alpha: 0=invisible, 1=opaque
color filler; filler = .95[blue,white];
picture bg, fg; 
bg = currentpicture; % save the current pic *before* filling the box
fg = image( 
  for e within bg:
    draw e if 5=colormodel e: withcolor alpha[colorpart e, filler] fi;
  endfor
);
clip fg to box; 

fill box withcolor filler;  
draw fg;
draw box;

endfig;
end.
```

### Notes

Given a picture variable `p` the syntax `for e within p` steps through all the components of the picture `p`.  Each `e` is also a picture variable.  `colormodel e` returns the colour model being used for the element; 5 means the usual RGB colours, 0 means it's not coloured.  `colorpart e` returns the colour of the element.

So what the loop does is redraw everything in the saved copy of the current picture, and for each element that's coloured using an RGB colour it recolours it using a colour that is `alpha` of the way between the original colour and the colour used as a filler.  This creates an approximate illusion of transparency.

It's tempting to write `for e within currentpicture` but for some unknown reason, this does not work.  You have to save `currentpicture` to a picture variable and then step through that.

Comment: An image like this would be even easier in `tikz` ;-)

Comment: @daleif Indeed - but that's not necessarily a good thing!  Transparency is a feature best used sparingly in my opinion.  But it is *possible* in plain MP, and if you really wanted you could implement macros in MP to produce an interface as simple as that in TikZ.

Comment: I know there is transparency in the `metafun` package for metapost. But I could not get it to compile in the test I did.